# How to prevent access to tables, views and stored procedures in an Azure SQL database?

Tags: azure-sql-database, ssms

Can someone let me know how to go about preventing users (other than the creator) from being able to access or view certain tables, views, and stored procedures?

I'm currently using SSMS, but not sure which options to select:

[image]

I have updated this question to address the solution that @Bhavani provided below, as his suggestion didn't appear to work.

I added an Azure Active Directory user to the database as follows:

```
CREATE USER [peter@xxxxxx.co.uk] 
FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER 
WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = config;

ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [peter@xxxxx.co.uk];
```

I then denied all access to a Table called dbo.UpdatedProducts as follows

[image]

Having completed the above, when peter@xxxxxx.co.uk access the database he can still read,select,alter etc.. on the table dbo.UpdatedProducts.

Can someone let me know if I have missed out a step?

Updated permissions for peter@xxxxx.co.uk

```
-- Revoke permissions explicitly if previously granted
REVOKE SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON dbo.UpdatedProducts TO [peter@xxxxx.co.uk];

-- Grant only the necessary permissions
--GRANT SELECT ON dbo.UpdatedProducts TO [peter@xxxxxx.co.uk];
DENY SELECT ON dbo.UpdatedProducts TO [peter@xxxxxx.co.uk];
```

With the above update, peter@xxxxx.co.uk is still able to select and on dbo.UpdatedProducts

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/logins-create-manage?view=azuresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a step-by-step guide on how to prevent users (other than the creator) from accessing or viewing certain database objects:

- Right-click on the table, view, or stored procedure and select "Properties."
- Go to the "Permissions" tab.
- Click on "Search" to find the user or role to which you want to grant or deny permissions, as shown below:

[image]

- In the "Explicit permissions for [user/role]" section, select "Deny" or "Grant" for the specific permissions you want to restrict. For example, if you want to access the table, view, or stored procedure data, you can grant permission to select the option, as shown below:

[image]

When working with AAD users, it's important to note that permissions are managed through roles and memberships. Instead of using `DENY` permissions, consider using a combination of `GRANT` and `REVOKE` to manage permissions. Deny permissions can be tricky to work with and might not always behave as expected due to inheritance.

```
-- Revoke permissions explicitly if previously granted
REVOKE SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON dbo.UpdatedProducts TO [peter@xxxxx.co.uk];

-- Grant only the necessary permissions
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.UpdatedProducts TO [peter@xxxxx.co.uk];
```

You have added the user to the `db_datareader` role, which has read access to all tables in the database. that is the reason for getting table after revoking, use below command to restrict access to the particular table:

```
DENY SELECT ON dbo.UpdatedProducts TO [peter@xxxxx.co.uk];
```

Comment: Hi Bhavani, this looks ideal. Thank you very much. I will check it out in the morning.

Comment: Hi @Bhavani, I have updated the question, as the solution you provided didn't appear to work.

Comment: @Patterson I have updated the answer according to your requirement can you check once?

Comment: going to check now.. Give me 10minutes

Comment: is it possible to revoke the ability for an AAD user to view a table. The suggestions you provided still allow peter@xxxxx.co.uk to view the table dbo.UpdatedProducts

Comment: I have updated the question. peter@xxxxx.co.uk is still able to view and select on dbo.UpdatedProducts

Comment: Hi @Bhavani, I just thought I would let you know that I deleted peter@xxxxx.co.uk and started again by adding his account as ```CREATE USER [peter@xxxxx.co.uk] FROM  EXTERNAL PROVIDER  WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[config]``` and then tried your suggestion ```REVOKE SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON dbo.UpdatedProducts TO [peter@xxxxx.co.uk];```, but peter@xxxx.co.uk was still able to select on dbo.UpdatedProducts

Comment: Try DENY SELECT ON dbo.UpdatedProducts TO [peter@xxxxx.co.uk]; command it is working from my side.

Comment: ok, I started from scratch by creating a new AAD user, ```--CREATE USER [barlow@xxxx.co.uk] FROM  EXTERNAL PROVIDER  WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[config]
--GO``` and explicityl gave the user access to just one table .. dbo.UpdatedProducts as follows ```GRANT SELECT ON dbo.UpdatedProducts TO [barlow@xxxxxx.co.uk];``` but barlow@xxxxxx.co.uk cannot see the dbo.UpdatedProducts. I have just done it, so may it needs time to proprogate, however I thought it would happen instantly. Is there something I'm doing wrong?